# Spring-boot: @Bean not resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting this error message:

> No suitable resolver for argument 0 of type 'org.springframework.context.MessageSource'

This is the related code:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler({DocumentAlreadyExistsException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error handleException(MessageSource messageSource, DocumentAlreadyExistsException e) {

        cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error error = new cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error();
        error.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        error.setMessage(messageSource.getMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), null, null));
        return error;

    }

}
```

By other hand, I've created this bean:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServicesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("messages/exceptions/document");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your configuration class is probably not scanned by Spring. Look what packages are scanned by your annotations and make sure it's in the right subpackages.

Comment: Why the MessageSource messageSource it is passed as param to the method?
Why is it not @Autowired/injected in the class constructor? And the method only receives the exception then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the bean, not on the method signature, but injected on the class (constructor or setter method):

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public ExceptionControllerAdvice(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({DocumentAlreadyExistsException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error handleException( DocumentAlreadyExistsException e) {

        cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error error = new cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error();
        error.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        error.setMessage(messageSource.getMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), null, null));
        return error;
    }
}
```